# How do I accept on a single route objects with array\single items using pydantic/fastapi?

Tags: python, rest, swagger, fastapi, variant

Say I have:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import Optional, List

class Create(BaseModel):
    code: List[str] = []
    args: List[str] = []
```

Wrapped into something like

```
@router.post('/new', status_code=201)
async def create_project(data: Create):
    pass
```

So that `code` and/or `args` is an array or single value for the requestor?

Such that request to single rout  could contain any of this:

```
{code: "code", args: "arg"}
{code: ["code"], args: "arg"}
{code: ["code"], args: ["arg"]}
{code: "code", args: ["arg"]}
```

And always call handler with real type that uses lists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pydantic models accept [`Union`](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/types/#unions) for the field definition, e.g.:

```py
from typing import List, Union

class Create(BaseModel):
    code: Union[str, List[str]] = []
    args: Union[str, List[str]] = []
```

In this case, both `code` and `args` will accept either a `str` or a list/array of `str`s.

Both `code` and `args` will default to an empty `list`.

The rest of the code stays the same, e.g.:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, status

app = FastAPI()

@app.post("/create", status_code=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
async def create_project(data: Create):
    return data
```

Calling the endpoint with single item:

```
$ curl -i -X 'POST' 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/create' \
    -H 'accept: application/json' \
    -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    -d '{"code": "code", "args": "arg"}'

HTTP/1.1 201 Created
date: Sun, 29 Aug 2021 10:25:57 GMT
server: uvicorn
content-length: 28
content-type: application/json

{"code":"code","args":"arg"}
```

Calling the endpoint with multiple items:

```
$ curl -i -X 'POST' 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/create' \
    -H 'accept: application/json' \
    -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    -d '{"code": ["code"], "args": ["arg"]}'

HTTP/1.1 201 Created
date: Sun, 29 Aug 2021 10:27:03 GMT
server: uvicorn
content-length: 32
content-type: application/json

{"code":["code"],"args":["arg"]}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have many possibilities, one of the universal ones is to use a [validator](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/validators/) (or root validator), and in it parse single values into a list. Like so:

```
class Create(BaseModel):
    code: List[str] = []

    @validator('code', pre=True)
    def code_validate(cls, values):
        if not isinstance(values, list):
            values = [values]
        return values
```

Comment: Sadly I get  422 Unprocessable Entity from fastapi even after applying this with allow_reuse=True

Comment: In this case, minimal reproducible example is needed